# Creating a WC_Product_Subscription_Variation and setting the required post meta (period and period_interval) via PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to create a WC_Product_Variable_Subscription and the connected
WC_Product_Subscription_Variation(s) via PHP

Creating **WC_Product_Variable** and **WC_Product_Variation** seems to be pretty straight forward (the class from which the classes I create inherit) but I am having troubles setting the required

interval,
period and
length

properties (e.g make the subscription price 200$ every month for 6 month.)

When creating a 
**new WC_Product_Variation**
and the connected new 
**WC_Product_Subscription_Variation(s)**

is it as simple as setting the post meta

```
[_subscription_period] => Array
    (
        [0] => month
    )

[_subscription_period_interval] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[_subscription_length] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )
```

manually after creating the variations ?
Does anyone have a working code example for that ?

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction !

m.

Answer (score 0):

Once again I should have reviewed the underlying code in more detail before posting this question - sorry to anyone who has actually spent time with this question.

Concerning the actual answer:

if the **WC_Product_Variable_Subscription** (which is not a subscription but a product type - naming might be a bit confusing) has been created and the required variations have been created / connected to it the product variations can be updated via the post meta data.

e.g.

```
update_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_subscription_period', 'week');
update_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_subscription_period_interval', 1);
update_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_subscription_length', 4);
```

as a tip: if you search for a way to create the variations  you can have a look at the **createAllProductVariations** method of the data_store

e.g.

```
$data_store = $product->get_data_store();    
$data_store->create_all_product_variations($product, $maxVariations);
$data_store->sort_all_product_variations($product->get_id());
```